# Any way to restore my deleted settings in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally deleted all my settings from the settings.json file of Microsoft VS Code directly from Code. Is there any way to restore my settings? I made a lot of tweaks to Code and would like it to be just the way it was before.

- I don't have a backup of the file
- Settings sync was not turned on

Comment: Recover your backup of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Was Settings Sync turned on?
In that case, you have got the chances.
For more reference: [vscode-link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync)